# Ntfs Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and windows 10

Tags: ntfs

Does the ntfs used in Ubuntu cause corruption when used with windows 10
When I saved files to a memory card some of the directories said corrupted when I had saved content under Ubuntu and then went to read the same content under latest version of windows 10.
Is fat 32 the safer format for cross OS support

Comment: I have used the NTFS implementation in Ubuntu daily for years without any corruption due to the software. However, I have lost many memory cards of various formats to hardware failure. Memory cards wear out.

Answer (score 0):

this was not a case of memory card wearing out.  i think that when i purchased the pc and the fact that the previous owner had used an upgrade edition of windows 10 vs a full install stuff was not 100% functional.  i did find that the default windows 10 settings of turning off the power to the usb and sdxc controller may have caused the corruption.  i did notice that when i formatted it as ntfs under ubuntu i had to assign a letter to it under windows 10 as it did not auto mount as it does in ubuntu